# What does the phrase "rotating the pieces and lining up edges" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a space adventure game's description:

> In an activity, you have to to reassemble a torn-up map by grabbing
>   and **rotating the pieces and lining up edges.**

I am confused about the meaning of the phrase **rotating the pieces and lining up edges**. Maybe it is because I have always been afraid of drawing maps. :)

Answer (score 1):

It says that the map has been torn up. So the map is now in many pieces. You have to put the pieces together, like a jigsaw puzzle. To do that, you have to figure out which way is up on each of the pieces. You have to ROTATE them so that the right side is on top. Then you have to fit the pieces together. You have to figure out where the EDGE of one piece fits the EDGE of another piece. You have to LINE UP the two EDGES.